# Workflows -Conditional Branches

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, branch

I'm creating a workflow for a form.

Form is an approval form that requires 4 approvers or rejected.

I can get the approvals to work but not the rejections.

I'm using Designer 2007.

My work flow looks like this:

Step 1: 
Condition:  If Created equals created
Action:Email to notify all approvers.

Step 2:
Condition: Else If TomR equals yes
if TomA equals yes
Action:  Send an email to creator
then send an email to...

From here I have created conditional branches for the other 3 approvers using the same steps as above.

I don't believe I'm understanding what I'm doing obviously.

Answer (score 0):

The out of the box approval workflow should cater for this? Is there a reason that it does not and you need to build your own?